# LARAVEL UNIT TEST - Opposite of seeInDatabase

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.1

In Laravel 5.1 there is a method that asset if some data are in database using the seeInDatabase($table,$fields)...

Is there a way to assert if the some data arent in database? Something like dontSeeInDatabase... Similiar to [dontSeeJson](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/CrawlerTrait.html#method_dontSeeJson)

Comment: How about `! seeInDatabase()`?

Comment: NO seeInDatabase does not return boolean value.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Laravel v5.6**

Assertion name has changed

```
->assertDatabaseMissing(string $table, array $data, string $connection = null)
```

the opposite would be

```
->assertDatabaseHas(string $table, array $data, string $connection = null)
```

**Previous Laravel versions**

There are two ways:

```
->notSeeInDatabase($table, array $data)
```

and

```
->missingFromDatabase($table, array $data)
```

One is just an alias for the other.

For a full list of available testing methods take a look at the traits located at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing`

Comment: the syntax has changed recently, here are the latest API docs: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithDatabase.html#method_seeInDatabase

Comment: Lumen 5.8 still uses the old syntax. The new "assert" syntax does not work there.

Answer (score 6):

In recent versions of Laravel (5.4 as of now) , `seeInDatabase` and `missingFromDatabase` methods are not available. Instead, there are `assertDatabaseHas` and `assertDatabaseMissing` methods. Usage is the same:

`->assertDatabaseHas($table, array $data)`

`->assertDatabaseMissing($table, array $data)`

So, if you're using recent versions of Laravel as of now and doing testing, you should try `assertDatabaseMissing()`.