# Laravel assertDatabaseMissing weird behavior

Tags: laravel, database, integration-testing, laravel-middleware

This is my code (test). There is no other code in this method:

```
$this->withoutMiddleware();  
$fc = factory(\App\Models\FaqCategory::class)->create();
$response = $this->delete('/admin/faq-categories/'.$fc->id);
$response->assertStatus(302);
$response->assertRedirect('/admin/faq-categories/');
$this->assertDatabaseMissing('faq_categories', ['id' => $fc->id]);
```

I have no idea why, but last assertion fails, even if row does not exists in database. Object was deleted in 3rd line, but 6th line fails anyway.

EDIT:
I figured it out. I am using model binding in my controllers, so i can not just put $this->withoutMiddleware() in test, becouse route model binding will not work (something needs to be done in middlewares).

Comment: As a comment: this is not a very good Unit test, which is implied by `assertDatabaseMissing`. you should call functions, not routes. And what is `$this->delete` in this context?

Comment: `$this->delete(...)` is a `DELETE` http request to the given URL. It is no unit test, but a feature or integration test, whatever you want to call it.

Comment: Are you certain that your factory creates and stores the model successfully? You may wanna add a `$this->assertDatabaseHas('faq_categories', ['id' => $fc->id])` check before calling the route.

Comment: @Thomas
Actually, method that deletes model is not a part of my app, there is no need to test Eloquent methods. I want to test that user can access the route that deletes model and it will process successfully.

Comment: @Namoshek 
Status assertion passes the test so model must exists, otherwise it should fail (status 404).

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, either it depends on what your DB driver supports and not (cascade is not supported by sqlite and so on), or it's as simple (and stupid as it was in my case) that the item was soft deleted.

see

[LARAVEL UNIT TEST - Opposite of seeInDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355020/laravel-unit-test-opposite-of-seeindatabase)

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/super-weird-test-failure